# How to replace a base class with a subclass -- even when base methods return new base class instances

Tags: python, pandas

I have a subclass that inherits from `pandas.DataFrame` and adds some new methods specific to my implementation. Those methods act on and return a modified version of self (basically just repeating the DataFrame pattern of chainable methods that already exists, but with extended functionality):

```
class Subclass(pandas.DataFrame):

    def new_method(self):
        return Subclass(self.transform(...))
```

When I define my own methods, it's easy to return new `Subclass` instances. However, when I call methods from the base class that aren't overridden, the returned result is a new DataFrame, *not* a new Subclass. So I lose any new functionality from my instance as soon as I use base class methods.

Is there a way (without overriding *every* method in the `pandas.DataFrame` base class that I suspect may be used in Subclass) of forcing the base class methods to return Subclass instances? In other words, wherever the `DataFrame` constructor is used within a `Subclass` instance, silently replace it with a `Subclass` constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Looking at the documentation, it appears there is a solution provided for this.](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/development/extending.html#override-constructor-properties)

In your class, you need to override this property and return your own class.

```py
@property
def _constructor(self):
    return Sublclass
```

To keep with this pattern, you should also replace any `Subclass` calls when returning objects with references to `_constructor` so that any subclasses of your own class can also return `Subsubclass` rather than `Subclass`.